# How to pass data/object from fragment to activity in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, fragment

I am tring to pass a list of datas from a fragment to a activity using intent. When sending the data from fragment, the data is exist. But in activity the its says data is null. I am not sure if the way i pass the data is correct or not or is there any better way to pass the data from fragment to activity?

In Fragment

```
private var selectedBankCard: Channels = Channels //get a list of data from BE
    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        when (view?.id) {
            R.id.bankcard_layout -> {
                    try {
                        if (activity != null) {
                            val intent =
                                Intent(context, BankCardListActivity::class.java)
                            if (selectedBankCard != null) {
                                intent.putExtra("BANKCARDINFORMATION", selectedBankCard) //upon debug, i can see a selectedBankCard is not null
                            }
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 10001)
                        }
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                     
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In Activity

```
class AutoReloadBankCardListActivity : BaseActivity() {
private lateinit var channels: Channels
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.bank_card)
        if (intent == null) {
            return
        }
        channels = intent.getSerializableExtra("BANKCARDINFORMATION") as Channels // upon debug, getSerializableExtra returns null
        
    }


class Channels : Serializable {
    var newCard = false
    var disable = false
    var disableCode: String = ""
    var description: String = ""
    var channelType: String = ""
    var payBrands: List<String>? = null
    var channelIndex: String = ""
    var payToolType: String = ""
    var selected = false
    var payBrand: String = ""
    var extendInfo: ExtendInfo? = null
    var disableReason: String = ""
    var icon: String = ""
    var chargeIndex: String = ""

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the class definition of `selectedBankCard`?

The type of selectedBankCard must implement the Serializable interface, otherwise the data cannot be obtained in the Activity.

```kotlin
data class Channels(
    var newCard = false,
    var disable = false,
    var disableCode: String = "",
    var description: String = "",
    var channelType: String = "",
    var payBrands: List<String>? = null,
    var channelIndex: String = "",
    var payToolType: String = "",
    var selected = false,
    var payBrand: String = "",
    var extendInfo: ExtendInfo? = null,
    var disableReason: String = "",
    var icon: String = "",
    var chargeIndex: String = ""
) : Serializable
```

Comment: Parcelable also works, so `@Parcelize` is a good bet (even if the OP used serializable initially)

Comment: You can try it. Whether it can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> better way to pass the data from fragment to activity?

Better way is listener. You can use interface or lambda in kotlin.

Your fragment. Category is your data/object in this example

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
        var listener: ((category: Category) -> Unit)? = null


        fun sendCategoryToListener(category: Category) {
            listener?.invoke(category)
        }
}
```

Code in your activity

```
val fragment = MyFragment()
fragment.listener = { category ->
    // Do what you want with your object
}
```

Comment: This will break after process death, as the system recreates the Fragment, not the developer. Alternately, the developer's code overwrites the system's fragment restoration logic, and either duplicates fragments, or erases restored state. Either way, this is never correct, unless the Fragment is checked for existence using its fragment tag first to see if it's non-null.

Comment: I have tested on process death, it works well. Did you test this code on process death?

Comment: It only works if you set the listener also after `findFragmentByTag` too and not just instantiation

Comment: I'm creating a fragment in onCreate() method of an activity. Here is gist url: https://gist.github.com/Shamsidin/24ac22a25a1553962035a0c3b89e91fb

Comment: this only works because on process death, you're replacing the fragment restored by the system

Answer (score 0):

if you use this code to start a fragment from an activity then you can easily get the return data like this.

Code to start fragment

```
 fun addFragment(
    fragment: Fragment,
) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(BACK_STACK)
        .commit()
}

addFragment(ABCFragment(item->{//here the item is your return data}))
```

You can add fragment like this

and to get return data you can add fragment like this

```
 addFragment(ABCFragment( private val returnData: (item: ABCModel) -> Unit,))
```

and in fragment write this code

```
    class ABCFRagment(private val returnData: (item: ABCModel) -> Unit,):Fragment{
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    item.invoke(data)
}}
```

and in activity you can get your return data as item